# How do I add a key to each array in a multidimensional array if it meets certain criteria in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, nested-loops

Lets say I have an array like:

```
$thing = Array
(
    [test1] => something
    [test2] => something
    [info] => yes
    [array] => Array
        (
            [test1] => something else
            [test2] => something else
            [info] => maybe
            [array] => Array
                (
                    [test1] => something
                    [info] => yes
                )

        )
)
```

How can I write a function that goes through `$thing` and adds a key to each part called 'valid' with a value of `TRUE` if the value of 'info' is 'yes' and `FALSE` otherwise?

I basically want the final array to look like:

```
$final = Array
(
    [test1] => something
    [test2] => something
    [info] => yes
    [valid] => TRUE //add this
    [array] => Array
        (
            [test1] => something else
            [test2] => something else
            [info] => maybe
            [valid] => FALSE //add this
            [array] => Array
                (
                    [test1] => something
                    [info] => yes
                    [valid] => TRUE //add this
                )

        )

)
```

I'm writing a library for codeigniter that manages a site map and provides easy ways to get the breadcrumb and navigation tree for a page but am stuck at a part where I need to do something like this.

The main question that I can't figure out is:
**How do I go through the array and add a key to each part? Also there can be an infinite amount of arrays in arrays.**

Thanks!

Comment: Could you not just use `info` instead, as that appears to duplicate data.  If not, just right a recursive function that takes an array, adds the `valid` key and calls itself on the `array` key if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
$thing = Array
(
        "test1" => "something",
        "test2" => "something",
        "info" => "yes",
        "array" => Array
        (
                "test1" => "something else",
    "test2" => "something else",
    "info" => "maybe",
                "array" => Array
                (
                        "test1" => "something",
                        "info" => "yes"
                )
        )
);



function validPush($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
           $array[$key] = validPush($value);

        if($key == "info")
            $array['valid'] = ($value == "yes") ? true : false ;
    }
    return $array;
}

var_dump(validPush($thing));
```

Output

```
array
  'test1' => string 'something' (length=9)
  'test2' => string 'something' (length=9)
  'info' => string 'yes' (length=3)
  'array' => 
    array
      'test1' => string 'something else' (length=14)
      'test2' => string 'something else' (length=14)
      'info' => string 'maybe' (length=5)
      'array' => 
        array
          'test1' => string 'something' (length=9)
          'info' => string 'yes' (length=3)
          'valid' => boolean true
      'valid' => boolean false
  'valid' => boolean true
```

Answer (score 2):

This feels like you're adding redundant information. Why can't you just re-use the data in the array - i.e.

```
[info] => yes
```

Comment: I agree in this example I could. In the actual code I am writing though I need the function that will go through the whole array and check some stuff, and then append another key.

Comment: The problem I'm having is how do I append the key?

Comment: @TomJenkinson: An important rule on SO - if you simplify the question, expect simplified answers.

Comment: I know. I've edited it again and the bit in bold is the main question.

Answer (score 2):

```
function setInfoTrueFalse($array){
    if(isset($array['info']) && $array['info']=='yes'){ 
        $array['valid']=TRUE;
    }else{
        $array['valid']=FALSE;
    }
    foreach($array as $key => $val){ # if we don't know the name of possible arrays, loop though
        if(is_array($val)){
            # loop one layer deeper if we have another array, could combine with the 'info' check if yes to that means this array exists and is an array
            $array[$key]=setInfoTrueFalse($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

$final=setInfoTrueFalse($thing);
```

Comment: OK. Thanks. I forgot to mention thought that it could be an infinite amount of layers...

Comment: changed value to valid (typo)

Comment: @TomJenkinson: Learn about recursive functions, as Dave has shown above (+1) and I mentioned before.

Comment: if your example `array` isn't named that, you could then do a foreach and see if each element is an array, and if so, run the function on it.  This assumes that all the layers deep actually have an array element called `array`

Comment: I've tried writing a recursive function but kept getting lost when trying to do this particular thing. Is it possible with `array_walk_recursive`?

Comment: @TomJenkinson: Dave has written one above...  `array_walk_recursive()` is insufficiently selective I would think.

Comment: added a foreach in case you don't know the name of potential arrays in the array that you may want to run this on as well.  This will look in any nested arrays for 'info' elements and set the 'valid=true' if they exists.  Make sure that is what you want.

Comment: @Dave: Think you were robbed there, your code is a lot better than the accepted answer.  Better style too.

Comment: Sorry. I can only accept one answer but I agree that they both work.

Answer (score 0):

why not jus add the value to the first array and consider it valid for the rest.

edit: do a recursive call, passing $array depending on how many dimensional array you got, here 3.

```
function add_array( $array) {  
    $array['info'] = 'yes';
 return $arr;
}
```

call:

```
 $final = add_array(add_array(add_array($final)));
```

Comment: The problem is that that won't also go into the arrays that are in $arr.